# What is happening in debug compilation that is causing the query to take longer to execute?

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

ServiceStack 3.9.69 via Nuget using SqlServer OrmLite dialect

I'm attempting to execute a parameterized stored procedure but am noticing an unusual slowness when the compilation mode is set to `debug`.  The method that is slow is `ConvertToList` below:

```
    Dim result = Db.Exec(Of List(Of Dto.FieldSample))(
        Function(cmd)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "up_GetFieldSample"
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@uploadID", uploadId))
            Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            Dim converted = reader.ConvertToList(Of Dto.FieldSample)()

            Return converted
        End Function)
```

(I know there is a `.SqlList` extension available, but I tried that first with the same results. I switched to `Exec` to get a better idea of where the issue was)

The stored procedure returns in 2-3 seconds when executed in non-debug mode, but 15-20 seconds in debug mode.  I understand that there is often tracing, etc included in debug compilation but I'm trying to figure out what is actually so slow.

What is happening in `debug` compilation that is causing the query to take longer to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected, there is some internal error handling/logging being performed during `ConvertToList` when it calls `PopulateWithSqlReader` [Source](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/290c498e0612a40b8c33eb49dd937a42d3849b1e/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteWriteExtensions.cs)

The underlying issue was a data type mismatch between my POCO (decimal?) and the database (int).  It wasn't until I hooked up a `LogManager.LogFactory = New ConsoleLogFactory()` that I could see that an exception was being thrown internally, logged, then moving on. The 235+ (rows) of exception handling was what was causing the delay.